# How can we have JBOSS MDB retry its connection if it fails at startup?

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss-mdb

We have a server app that is deployed across to server machines, each running JBOSS 4.2.2. We use JBOSS messaging with MDBs to communicate between the systems. Currently we need to start the servers in a very specific order so that JBOSS can connect properly. If a server starts and doesn't see its resources it never tries again. This is problematic and time consuming in testing when we're bouncing servers constantly. We believe that if we could specify a retry flag in JBOSS could reattempt to get the connection.

**Is there a flag/config option in JBOSS that would reattempt to obtain JMS connections on failure at startup?**

I am quite new to the JMS technology, so it is entirely possible that I have mixed up some terms here. Since this capability is to be used in house experimental or deprecated options are acceptable.

**Edit:** The problem is that a consumer starts up with no producer available and subsequently fails, never to try again. If a consumer and producer are up and the producer dies the consumer will retry for the producer to come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 95% sure that JBoss MDBs *do* retry connections like that. If your MDBs are not receiving messages as you expect, I think something else is wrong. Do the MDBs depend on any other resources. Perhaps posting your EJB descriptors (`META-IF/ejb-jar.xml` and `META-IF/jboss.xml`) would help.

Comment: At this time I cannot post the xml files. I realize this limits the amount of help you can provide.

Comment: As I have no other ideas, I'm guessing that it's something else. Thus the question as asked is answered.